# FIREBASE cant send into topics, but works fine if send into user segment

Tags: objective-c, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am currently asked to do separate project for development and production

i used this code for separete 2 different plist

```
if(ALLOW_SANDBOX)
{
    filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info_debug" ofType:@"plist"];
    FIROptions *options = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];

}else{
    [FIRApp configure];
}
```

this code works fine if i want to send into user segmented user, but cant work if i want to send into topics

even my subscribed topics not appear on topic list on firebase console.

any solving for this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: how to subscribe to topic? can u post your subscription code?

Comment: for (NSDictionary *topic in topics) {
   // do something with object
   
   NSString *topic_name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/topics/%@",[topic objectForKey:@"topic_name"]];
   // [START subscribe_topic]
   [[FIRMessaging messaging] subscribeToTopic:topic_name];
   NSLog(@"Subscribed to news topic");
   // [END subscribe_topic]
   
  }

i used foreach code because i need to retrieve from api the topic list

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (NSDictionary *topic in topics) {
        // do something with object

        NSString *topic_name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/topics/%@",[topic objectForKey:@"topic_name"]];
        // [START subscribe_topic]
        [[FIRMessaging messaging] subscribeToTopic:topic_name];
        NSLog(@"Subscribed to news topic");
        // [END subscribe_topic]

    }
```

i used foreach code because i need to retrieve from api the topic list
@saeed-rz

Comment: topic create on FIRBase when client subscribe to it, so at the first time you have not any topic in FirBase

Comment: i know, thats why i already wait until 24 hours for that topics appear at firebase console. but the topic not appear until now.

if i can send message with user segmented, my app doesnt have problem with firebase configuration, right?